# Why does shift() work on one array but not the other, unless applied generically on the other

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, shift

In the following code the compiler (at 'compile' time) makes no complaints about `groups.shift()` but complains that `depths.shift()` is not a function. What am I being blind to? (I tried renaming `depths`, retyping, etc.)

```
    const tag1x = (elem, content, groups = ['?','?','?'], depths = ['?','?'], optional = true, level = 0) => {
        let option = optional ? '?' : '';
        let template = `
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:<$1[^>]*?DDD(${depths.shift()}:[0-9]+)[^>]*>)$3
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:$2)
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:</$1[^>]*?DDD(${depths.shift()}:[0-9]+)[^>]*>)$3
            `;
        return form(template, elem, content, option);
    }
```

However, if I use `shift` generically it works fine on all counts:

```
    const tag1x = (elem, content, groups = ['?','?','?'], depths = ['?','?'], optional = true, level = 0) => {
        let option = optional ? '?' : '';
        let template = `
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:<$1[^>]*?DDD(${[].shift.call(depths)}:[0-9]+)[^>]*>)$3
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:$2)
            ${'\t'.repeat(level)}(${groups.shift()}:</$1[^>]*?DDD(${[].shift.call(depths)}:[0-9]+)[^>]*>)$3
            `;
        return form(template, elem, content, option);
    }
```

The above is fully functional.

Answer (score 0):

I misread the situation. The error was occurring at runtime, and thus pretty clearly because of a string input instead of an array input. A string input will get fixed up by `[].shift.call(myAccidentallyAString)` while, of course, a `shift()` call directly on the string is not a function.

It acts like `Array.isArray(myStuff) ? myStuff.shift() : [myStuff].shift()`, which makes sense because (I'll guess) `myStuff` is getting boxed to an object then called on by `shift()`.